# How to build OpenCV 4.5 from source on RaspberryPi 4?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile the **OpenCV 4.5 library from source** on a fresh install of Raspian and I'm running into a problem regarding the C++ standard. After running the cmake command from the build dir, in order to obtain the required makefiles, I get prompted with the message **"OpenCV 4.X requires c++11**. I tried modifying the CMakeLists.txt adding the set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) and also adfding a building flag using the -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++11' option but without luck. All options available here: [cmake build command + flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9HYR.png) I'm not sure how I could get past this and I could use some advice if someone encountered it before, any suggestions? TIA

Comment: Check your compiler version, is it something really old which doesn't support c++11?

Comment: The gcc version is 8.3.0. At first I thought maybe somehow this was not the default compiler that cmake would make use of and so I thought I could specify explicitly. Unfortunately it did not make any difference.

Comment: The output said it did use gcc-8 you may want to attempt to look into why cmake/checks/cxx11.cpp failed.

Comment: Wait a minute. does /usr/bin/c++ point to g++8.3. `ls /usr/bin/c++ -al` may help.

Comment: @drescherjm /usr/bin/c++ points to /etc/alternatives/c++...eventually. See link. As for the opencv/cmake/cxx11.cpp, I've checked it out and I can't really tell what's wrong. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s73EB.png)